# 'hash' url rewrite in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to rewrite `http://example.com/articles.html#first-article` with `http://example.com/articles/first-article`

Is it possible to rewrite?

I tried using following but didn't work for me:

```
RewriteRule ^articles/(.+)$ /articles\.html\#$1
```

Comment: As @fab answered, the fragment is not sent to the server. You could setup a catch-all page and use JavaScript to do the redirecting.

Comment: @Bouke: WRONG/ Read the [Apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/advanced.html#redirectanchors), please.

Comment: @BoReth it doesn't have anything to do with Apache actually. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3067491/is-the-anchor-part-of-a-url-being-sent-to-a-web-server. To reiterate; the server doesn't have access to the anchor, and therefore it cannot use the anchor in rewrite rules.

Comment: @Bouke: Well, it has everything to do with Apache because it is about **REDIRECTING**. If there is a rewrite rule inside "httpd.conf" or ".htacces" with a `RewriteRule .  /Dir1/Dir2/#ApacheAnchor [NE,R=301,L]`, for example, the **SERVER** will indeed redirect to that URL and the RESPONSE HEADER will contain something like: "Location:http://mydomain/Dir1/Dir2/#ApacheAnchor". Therefore, claiming that the ANCHOR or the fragment are NEVER sent to the server is not accurate, in my opinion.

Comment: @BoReth you’re confusing sending data **to** the server with receiving data **from** the server. The question is regarding basing a server-side redirect on headers received from the client.

Comment: Gosh that's confusing. In your question you have the # in your source string and in your example you've put the # in the target string. No wonder there are some mixed up answers below.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

No, it's not possible. The *URL fragment* (everything from `#` on) not even gets sent to the server.

Maybe you want to consider a JavaScript based solution, where the actual content will be loaded via AJAX dependent on the fragment. You will find some useful information about this method here: [What's the shebang/hashbang (#!) in Facebook and new Twitter URLs for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009380/whats-the-shebang-hashbang-in-facebook-and-new-twitter-urls-for)

Comment: This should be de-selected as the correct answer as it is incorrect. @faa's answer below is in fact correct.

Comment: Depends on the question. The answer of @faa is correct but it does not address the issue of the original poster.

Comment: Good point, I was a little tired when I read it all first time, my bad.

Comment: Question asks for a way to remove the "#" character (Called **ANCHOR** by Apache). You say "No, it's not possible" and "Redirecting to an anchor was not the question". Then, why do you answer it in the 1st line?

You also say: "The URL fragment (everything from # on) not even gets sent to the server." Completely **WRONG**, in my opinion.

The "URL fragment" is indeed **sent** when NOT escaped, as explained in Apache documentation. I have tried it myself and unless Apache is wrong and you are right, your statement is NOT accurate.

@Alameda answer does indeed answer the question, IMHO.

Comment: **This not an answer**. It is just a wrong suggestion, but it has a lot of upvotes (?). In fact, this statement is wrong: "No, it's not possible. The URL fragment (everything from # on) not even gets sent to the server."  Of course it is possible. Read the Apache documentation, please. I agree with @designermonkey. Can't downvote, for now, but I will when I have the required reputation.

Answer (score 45):

The `#` can be added in the substitution URL with the NE flag. Check:

- [This Apache link](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/advanced.html#redirectanchors) that describes specifically how to `redirect anchors`.
- [This W3C Protocols link](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/Fragment/draft-bos-http-redirect-00.txt) and [this one](http://www.w3.org/TR/cuap#uri).
- [This answer in SO is pretty complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2286402/url-fragment-and-302-redirects).
- [Another answer in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15106056/mod-rewrite-in-htaccess-with-paging-system).
- [Another answer in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15033757/mod-rewrite-keeps-anchor-link/15034083#15034083) (mine).

So, you may try this:

```php
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !articles\.html      [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/articles/([^/]+)/? [NC]
RewriteRule .*       /articles.html#%1           [R,NE,L]
```

Redirects

`http://example.com/articles/parameter`

To

`http://example.com/articles.html#parameter`

String `articles` is assumed to be fixed while `parameter` is assumed to be variable.

Comment: Redirecting **to** an anchor was not the question.

Comment: This doesn't answers this question but is useful

Comment: Similar problem here I can't solve. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31859377/why-does-this-htaccess-rewriterule-that-includes-a-fail

Comment: **Redirecting to an anchor is the question**. The title is: **'hash' url rewrite in .htaccess**, where HASH means ANCHOR. The example in the question is: `RewriteRule ^articles/(.+)$ /articles\.html\#$1`. Since there is an ANCHOR (#) in the target URL of the example, the question is clearly asking for a way to redirect to an ANCHOR. Now, this answer is important because it clarifies the common misconception that the **ANCHOR** never "...gets sent to the server", contrary to [Apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/advanced.html#redirectanchors).