# Hash(#) tag redirect in htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want to redirect my old website url to new website url. I wrote a redirect rule in .htaccess file. But the problem is, my old url contains a hash tag between the url params.

```
Redirect /de/home/#/de/about/blog/ https://www.example.com/about/blog/
```

Everything I've tried ignores the hash tag and either doesn't redirect at all. My old domain has the same host and after redesign, there are some changes in urls. This is the reason I want to redirect the old url.

If it is not possible using htaccess, is there any other methods to implement this?

or can I able to use the url without hash by matching the part of a url?
I mean rewrite like this;

Redirect /(*)/de/about/blog/ https://www.example.com/about/blog/

Can you guys please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What HTTP server software and version are you using ?

Comment: I am using apache server.

Comment: Hi I've one more doubt,

In htaccess, can I able to use the url without hash?
I mean rewrite rule like this;

Redirect /(*)/de/about/blog/ https://www.example.com/about/blog/

Comment: possible duplicate of ['hash' url rewrite in .htaccess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15133023/hash-url-rewrite-in-htaccess)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make redirect on client side:

```
    if (window.location.hash == "#/de/about/blog/") {
        window.location = 'http://google.com.ua';
    }
```

Comment: Hi,

Thank you. So in my case I need to write the code like this;

 if (window.location.hash == "/de/home/#/de/about/blog/") {
        window.location = 'https://www.example.com/about/blog/';
    }

Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, you can also use regular expressions

Comment: Hi I've one more doubt,

In htaccess, can I able to use the url without hash?
I mean rewrite rule like this;

Redirect /(*)/de/about/blog/ https://www.example.com/about/blog/

Comment: Yes, please have a look for `RewriteRule` and `RedirectMatch` directives.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I'll check.

Comment: Can you give me an example for this?

Answer (score 4):

The fragment identify is designed to identify *part of a document*, it is handled entirely client side and will never be sent to the server.

The only way to redirect based on it is with client side JavaScript.

Comment: Can you give an example for this javascript redirect?

Comment: @ArunChandran just set `window.location`

Comment: @Volodymyr Melnychuk ok. But first we need to check the condition. right? Can you give me a sample code for this?

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible using htaccess. Everything from `#` (*URL fragment*) is not sent to the server. The only way is using JavaScript, that's one of the reasons many people [don't like hashbang](http://danwebb.net/2011/5/28/it-is-about-the-hashbangs).

> **Once you hashbang, you can’t go back.** This is probably the stickiest
>   issue. Ben’s post put forward the point that when pushState is more
>   widely adopted then we can leave hashbangs behind and return to
>   traditional URLs. Well, fact is, you can’t. Earlier I stated that URLs
>   are forever, they get indexed and archived and generally kept around.
>   To add to that, cool URLs don’t change. We don’t want to disconnect
>   ourselves from all the valuable links to our content. If you’ve
>   implemented hashbang URLs at any point then want to change them
>   without breaking links the only way you can do it is by running some
>   JavaScript on the root document of your domain. Forever. It’s in no
>   way temporary, you are stuck with it.

You will find some useful information here: [What's the shebang/hashbang (#!) in Facebook and new Twitter URLs for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009380/whats-the-shebang-hashbang-in-facebook-and-new-twitter-urls-for)