# Implementing a htaccess 301 redirect with a hashtag

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I was wondering if it is possible to have a htaccess redirect (or rewrite) which includes hashtags(`#`). I want to basically get this working:

```
Redirect 301 /#!/contact http://www.example.com/contact
Redirect 301 /#!/news http://www.example.com/news
Redirect 301 /#!/partners http://www.example.com/partners
Redirect 301 /#!/products http://www.example.com/products
```

I've looked into rewrites as well and can't find anything that will work!

Thank you for your time.

Comment: possible duplicate of ['hash' url rewrite in .htaccess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15133023/hash-url-rewrite-in-htaccess)

Comment: It is not a `hashtag` (as in [`Twitter hashtag`](https://support.twitter.com/articles/49309-using-hashtags-on-twitter#), f.e.). It is called [`fragment identifier`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier); the hash symbol and the fragment identifier are interpreted by the browser and not sent to the server.

Answer (score 1):

No it will not work. You can redirect to a URL `with` a fragment but not from because anything after the fragment is not sent to the server.

Example using mod_rewrite which you would have to use to use the `NE` flag.

You can do this using the NE flag to not encode the fragment.

```
RewriteRule ^contact/?$ /#!/contact/ [L,R,NE]
```

But it will `not` work this way

```
RewriteRule ^#!/contact/?$ /contact [L,R,NE]
```

So for your situation, it will not work.