# Why does this .htaccess RewriteRule that includes a '#' fail?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Goal: Match URL and rewrite it to a query string.

Problem: Looks like the "#" (and everything after it) in the replacement string is being ignored.

Here's what I have:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+) web2.html#list?d=$1&n=$2 [L,NE]
```

This gets to `web2.html` but the url parameters (`d= & n=`) are never applied.

The goal is to allow a url like: `somewehere.com/55c26838e4b087b032b432c4/1/` to trigger a query like this: `somewehere.com/web2#list?d=54668494e4b09ffed41ff167&n=1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hash-tags are used on client-side only. Try to redirect your request, with `R` flag specified.

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+) web2.html#list?d=$1&n=$2 [R=301,NE,L]
```

If that doesn't work fork for you, take a look at HTML5 [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history). I think `pushState` method can help you.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, that may create the page properly (uses the parameters) but I need to have the original url display in the address bar (somewehere.com/55c26838e4b087b032b432c4/1/) and not change to somewehere.com/web2#list?d=54668494e4b09ffed41ff167&n=1

Comment: Why you need this? The hashtag (and everything from `#` on)  is never send to server, so you can't do anything with it on server side. Do you have any business logic in your application?

Comment: I need a unique page created by the parameters but the displayed url cannot have a '#' in the url. Why? I want to add an annotation tool that cannot use urls that contain '#" character. Other approaches are welcomed.

Comment: So, what's the problem just to pass the `d` and `n` parameters, without hashtag? That way you can they will be served as `GET` parameters on server side.

Comment: The "#list" in this case is a jQuery Mobile page. So, the correct page will not display.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85322/discussion-between-user1452893-and-unixarmy).

Comment: @kav You say: "The hashtag (and everything from # on) is never send to server" Where is the documentation to support such statement? That is not what Apache documentation says. Check this Apache [LINK](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/advanced.html#redirectanchors) to some explanation on that subject. It is pretty clear that **ANCHORS**, as Apache call them, are in fact SENT to the server when they are not escaped.