# Trouble 301 redirecting pages from old Wix site to new site

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, velo

My client's original site was built on Wix, and I have designed and built a new one on a new server.

I'm trying to 301 redirect some pages from the old site to their counterparts on the new one, and it doesn't seem to want to work properly, as each old URL simply goes straight to the home page.

Example case:

old URL: *example.com/#!clients/c1pen*

new URL: *example.com/stay-with-us*

I have the redirect set out like so in .htaccess:

Redirect 301 /#!clients/c1pen /stay-with-us

Can anyone shed some light on this for me?

Answer (score 0):

Hash-location (http://someurl/#hash-location) typically adresses an anchor in a html page and is not visible to the server rewrite rules. Consequently the matcher `#!clients/c1pen` does never match. See ['hash' url rewrite in .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15133023/hash-url-rewrite-in-htaccess)

Comment: I did come across <a href="http://www.thedriversgarage.com/web-technology/redirecting-hashbang-urls-wix-urls/">this article</a> later on after posting this question. It seeks to provide an answer, but I'm not sure how to edit my zml sitemap, as it's generated by Yoast SEO plugin. Once I have a full solution I'll post as an answer.

Comment: http://www.thedriversgarage.com/web-technology/redirecting-hashbang-urls-wix-urls/