# Rewrite fragment (value after hash '#') from a URL in PHP

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I've seen many samples in PHP here but no one answer to my needs.
Want to redirect URL with hash (#) such as myserver.com/anyslug/#anyanchor

I've learn the NE (not escape) parameter, but I do not know how to put here without to destroy all my .htaccess file :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^inc/.*$ index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Thanks,

Gregoor

Comment: `#anyanchor` is not passed to a server.

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15135130/5873008, or maybe you need  [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) and [parse_str](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php)

Comment: Thanks but  what will be these 3 lines of .htaccess file if the rule is not only for articles page folder but all files such as http://example.com/first-article#note1 (no articles) ? Thanks

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !articles\.html      [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/articles/([^/]+)/? [NC]
    RewriteRule .*       /articles.html#%1           [R,NE,L]